# Como otimizar o desempenho de meu aplicativo ao fazer resquisições HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, ios, xamarin, httpclient

Estou desenvolvendo um app usando **Xamarin.Forms**, mas tenho um problema. As configurações como cor, nome da empresa, imagem de capa e logo vem através de uma requisição de uma chamada ao **web service** cujo retorno é um **JSON**, mas todas as vezes tenho que puxar essas informações, o que pode afetar o desempenho de meu servidor. Existe alguma forma de otimizar isso, como um cache em que faço a requisição apenas uma vez e sempre que haver uma atualização das informações?

Comment: Talvez você consiga salvar em um localstorage.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/WebKit.WKWebsiteDataType.LocalStorage/

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o que deverá consumir mais seu tráfego e memória do lado do servidor é o envio de imagens serializadas. No Xamarin é possível utilizar o FFImageLoading, que possui um sistema de cache para imagens, e você poderá utilizar para evitar recuperá-las do servidor toda vez que rodar a aplicação.

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: Obrigado, mais eu gostaria também de armazenar o Json em cache para que o usuário não fique baixando todas as vezes que entrar no app.

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção que recomendo é no start da aplicação você baixa as imagens pro app e resolve seu problema..